# Including an export in .profile does not update path after login

Tags: bash, shell, kali-linux, .profile

I installed Kali Linux v2020.4 using i3-wm and have updated `.profile` [below] to include an exported `PATH`, as I assumed updating `.profile` would impact all shells (sh, Bash, Zsh, etc.).

After logging out/in, I'm not able to run a script that exists inside `Desktop`, but if I run `source ~/.profile`, then I'm able to execute it:

```bsh
export PATH="$HOME/Desktop:$PATH"

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
  # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
      . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
  PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
  PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

- This is strange behavior to me and has only occurred using Kali; I have no `~/bash_profile`, and don't want to include it in `~/.bashrc`, as I want it to be available for all shells

Comment: Does the issue affect all shells? or just Bash?

Comment: The issue affects all shells

Comment: Do all shells use `~/.profile` by default _(for example, I don't believe Zsh does)_? What shells are being used besides Bash? You may also want to check out the `.profile` man page via `man .profile`, or some variant thereof, and have you tried adding it to `/etc/profile` instead of `~/.profile`?

Comment: @JW0914 I changed my default shell back to bash, using `chsh`, and the problem persists.
Also I edited `/etc/profile` to include `export PATH="$HOME/Desktop:$PATH"` and still nothing in `PATH`.

Comment: That sounds like it's specific to Kali's set up, so the best place to look for an answer will likely be Kali's man page for `profile` _(I could also very be wrong, as I'm more familiar with Zsh than Bash and other shells)_